# how can I solve group by error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody point me out where I am messing with below query and how I can correct it.

Error I am getting is :

SQL Server Database Error: Column 'A.competitor_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Line No-1 column no-0

```
SELECT A.competitor_id, A.Competitor_Name,    

(((AVG(A.Final_Price_Shipping)/AVG(D.Final_Price_Shipping))*100)-100) as [Final Price Shipping Index],                  
  (((AVG(A.Final_Price)/AVG(D.Final_Price))*100)-100) as [Final Price Index],                   
  (((AVG(A.Regular_price)/AVG(D.Regular_price))*100)-100) as [Regular Price Index]                  

from 


(SELECT A.competitor_id,C.Competitor_Name, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY  A.competitor_id) as Row_Count,
avg(Final_Price) Final_Price,avg(Final_Price_Shipping) Final_Price_Shipping,
avg(Regular_price) as Regular_price  ,SUM(A.Competitor_id) as cnt_NL
from [Tb_Competitor_Product_Info_New] A with (nolock)
inner join Tb_Competitor C on C.Competitor_Id=A.Competitor_ID
 where A.Competitor_id in (1)
  group by A.Competitor_ID,C.Competitor_Name) As A,




  (SELECT A.competitor_id, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY  A.competitor_id) as Row_Count,
avg(Final_Price) Final_Price,avg(Final_Price_Shipping) Final_Price_Shipping,
avg(Regular_price) as Regular_price  ,SUM(A.Competitor_id) as cnt_NL
from [Tb_Competitor_Product_Info_New] A with (nolock)
 where A.Competitor_id in (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
  group by A.Competitor_ID ) As D
```

Comment: you are using A.Competitor_ID in the group by clause and you are selecting it using small case, not sure if sql is not case-sensitive, also the error means that you need to select that field that you want to use in the group by clause

Answer (score 1):

Just add GROUP BY to the end of your query and also your A and D tables have to be joined I guess:

```
SELECT A.competitor_id, A.Competitor_Name,    

(((AVG(A.Final_Price_Shipping)/AVG(D.Final_Price_Shipping))*100)-100) 
    as [Final Price Shipping Index],                  
(((AVG(A.Final_Price)/AVG(D.Final_Price))*100)-100) as [Final Price Index],                   
(((AVG(A.Regular_price)/AVG(D.Regular_price))*100)-100) 
    as [Regular Price Index]                  

from 
(.....) As A
INNER JOIN (.....) As D on A.competitor_id=D.competitor_id

GROUP BY A.competitor_id, A.Competitor_Name
```